# Scala Type Mismatch when using generic java classes and inheritance

Tags: java, scala, generics, types

I'm writing a Scala extension for a Java application which makes use of generics:

The Java Code I want to use from Scala looks like this:

```
package example;
interface Base<T> {}
class Inherit<T> implements Base<T> {
    Base<T> other;
    Inherit(Base<T> other) {this.other = other;}
}

class Other implements Base<Double> {}

class Show {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Inherit<Double>(new Other());
    }
}
```

and I want to write (In Scala)

```
val b = new Inherit[Double](new Other())
```

but this fails with a Type Mismatch Error

```
found   : example.Other
required: example.Base[Double]
```

whereas the same statement works just fine when using only scala classes or only java classes.

Im using Scala 2.11.8 because other parts of the application also use this version.

How can I work around this problem?
Thanks

Edit: using

```
val b = new Inherit[Double](new Other().asInstanceOf[Base[Double]])
```

fixed the Problem, thank you Bubletan

Comment: Does `new Other().asInstanceOf[Base[Double]]` work?

Comment: Cast is rarely the right solution. Better to use `new Other[Double]`

Comment: @cchantep how should `new Other[Double]` work as it is no generic class but only extends from a generic class?

Comment: Then just let the inference work `new Inherit(new Other)`